# How to check if employee name is already exist in sharepoint using Powerapps

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps-canvas

I am trying to check if the employee name exists in the SharePoint list then I am trying to showing an error message

> Please select other Employee name, you selected a name that already exists in the database

See my SharePoint table here:

[image]

Employeename `runjan` is already stored in Sharepoint database if employee name already in database then I want to show an error on submit button

See below what I am tried:

[image]

employee name Datacard

[image]

I am writing these on submit button

```
OnSelect    If(CountRows(Filter(sourcename,EmployeeName = DataCardValue22.SelectedItems)) > 0,Notify("Please Select  Other Employee Name,you selected name already exist in database",NotificationType.Error))
```